# How to customize error message with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to show a custom message error with TensorFlow matrix, when the matrix has a determinant equals to 0, the inverse cannot be calculated but can't achieve to show message error with my function. My code is structured like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf
def inversematricx(arg):
    args = tf.convert_to_tensor(arg, dtype=tf.float32)
    try:
        return tf.matrix_inverse(args)
    except:
        raise ValueError("Determinant is 0. Input is not invertible")

mat1=tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]) # Determinant is 0 for mat1
mat2=tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 4.0], [3.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]])

inverse=inversematricx(mat1)

with tf.Session() as sess: 

    result = sess.run(inverse)    
    print(result)
```

## results for mat2

> [[ 0.17647055 -0.82352936  0.47058824]  [-0.88235289  1.11764693
>   -0.35294116]  [ 0.64705878 -0.35294113  0.05882351]]

But for mat1 which determinant is equals to 0, I want to force output
for ValueError message, not the error generated:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Input is not invertible.
     [[Node: MatrixInverse_21 = MatrixInverse[T=DT_FLOAT, adjoint=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Const_69)]]

Caused by op 'MatrixInverse_21', defined at:
    File "D:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.0Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 227, in <module>
main()
....
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input is not invertible.
 [[Node: MatrixInverse_21 = MatrixInverse[T=DT_FLOAT, adjoint=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Const_69)]]
```

Comment: one way is to use `tf.cond` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) to check whether the determinant is non-zero, and `tf.Print` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) to print the message

Comment: Currently, it is not possible to catch graph exceptions. refer to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10332)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution with tf.Print on a custom function like as follow:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
def checkMatrixInverse(arg):
    f=tf.matrix_determinant(arg).eval() #get determinant value
    args = tf.convert_to_tensor(arg, dtype=tf.float32)
    inv=tf.matrix_inverse(args) 
    err='Input is not invertible:'    
    if(f==0):
        return tf.Print(err,[err], name="NotInvertible")
    else:
        return tf.Print(inv, [inv], name="Inverse")

noninverse=checkMatrixInverse(mat1) #output b'Input is not invertible:' 

inverse=checkMatrixInverse(mat2) 
#output:
#[[ 0.17647055 -0.82352936  0.47058824]
# [-0.88235289  1.11764693 -0.35294116]
# [ 0.64705878 -0.35294113  0.05882351]]
```